# htop inaccurate on macOS

Tags: macos, htop

I'm trying to monitor the resource usage on an iMac 'remotely' (it's actually in Target Display Mode), so I installed htop via Homebrew.

The problem is, htop doesn't seem to be accurate in displaying what processes are using CPU resources. For instance, in the screenshot, all of the cores are 100% busy but htop displays nothing (it should show the 'FahCore_a7' process as consuming all the CPU, if I look at Activity Monitor on the target this is what's happening). This happens remotely via SSH or logged into the target directly.

How can I get htop to show resource usage correctly or is there another command I could use?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The various `*top`commands return *approximate* values, useful for a quick overview of what's going on. For detailed, precise values go for e.g. sar(1).